# applying formatting for cell based on result(true or false) in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-formatting, vba

I am trying to format cells based on values entered in cell. The cells represent multiplication sheet. After entering data B2 cell, if result is multiple of its row and column I.e 2 x  2  = 4 it should be green , otherwise it should be red . In short, I want to make this a multiplication trainer sheet. I tried using an if condition, but couldn't figure out how to put color for true and false.

The conditional formatting works fine when each cell of dest sheet [dest sheet to test multiplication skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEGAs.jpg)  is referred whith source sheet from which tables can be learned referred with each cell of source sheet . When I tried to specify ranges in condition of formatting it throws an error and it says only map one cell instead of range. Its rather hard to map each and every cell to compare result . Please help me to format to differentiate true and false after entering value into cell.
you can download my file from here . http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00186543650788471896

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: thanks for reply @ManishChristian . you can download my excel file from here .  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00186543650788471896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the range you would like to format, enter conditional formatting:

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply @Abe Gold.  i tried to refer range as you shown . but its showing error (view error on this link  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=41671272984236660366
  ) . to apply conditional formatting i have to select each and every cell to compare it with other cell . I need a way to mark cell with green if entered value is exactly same as result else it should be truned to red . I just want to differentiate between right and wrong after cell is filled. you can download my file from here.  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00186543650788471896

Comment: problem solved looks like the formula i typing is wrong